# When creating a facebook tab, how can i check if the user is accessing the page through facebook

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, redirect

I am trying to put a redirect on the iframe page I am creating for a facebook tab to make sure that those accessing the pages outside of FB will be directed to the application.

Everything I have done so far has caused problems with the meta data not being able to be accessed by FB and so on with the redirect causing a conflict.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know that you are inside a facebook iframe is to check and see if you have been passed a `signed_request` (and that it is valid).

Here is a link to another SO question that dealt with the same sort of issue.
[How to know if my page is running in a facebook iframe or not](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7783786/how-to-know-if-my-page-is-running-in-a-facebook-iframe-or-not)